# Multiple virtual Joystick use simultaneously in As3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, multi-touch

I currently making a space shooting game on android (A.K.A : Hell Bullet). So I made a base class for 2 joysticks that I use for Move and Fire independently. Right now my code work if I only move one at time, but not simultaneously. So I made some research and find about Multitouch, I tried some things and nothing work correctly.

Anyone know why ?

**Joystick.as** *(With mouseEvent that work one at time)* :

```
package LP {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Joystick extends MovieClip {

    private var _startX: Number = 0;
    private var _startY: Number = 0;
    private var _tension: Number = 0.3;
    private var _xSpeed: Number = 0;
    public var _isDragging: Boolean = false;
    public var _angle: int;
    private var _radius: int;
    public var _amplitudeX: Number;
    public var _amplitudeY: Number;

    public function Joystick() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageInit);
    }

    private function stageInit(e: Event): void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageInit);

        _startX = x;
        _startY = y;
        _radius = background.width / 2

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, on_mouseDown);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, on_mouseUp);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, on_enterFrame);
    }

    protected function on_mouseDown(e: MouseEvent): void {
        _isDragging = true;
    }


    protected function on_mouseUp(e: MouseEvent): void {
        _isDragging = false;
    }

    protected function on_enterFrame(e: Event): void {

        if (_isDragging) {
            _angle = Math.atan2(root.mouseY - _startY, root.mouseX - _startX) / (Math.PI / 180);
            rotation = _angle;
            stick.rotation = -_angle;

            stick.x = mouseX;
            if (stick.x > _radius) {
                stick.x = _radius;
            }
        } else {
            _xSpeed = -stick.x * _tension;
            stick.x += _xSpeed;
        }

        _amplitudeY = Math.sin(_angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * (stick.x / 8);
        _amplitudeX = Math.cos(_angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * (stick.x / 8);


    }


}

}
```

And this is my attempts with **MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE** *(doesn't work, nothing happened and no error)*

```
package LP {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

public class Joystick extends MovieClip {

    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

    private var _startX: Number = 0;
    private var _startY: Number = 0;
    private var _tension: Number = 0.3;
    private var _xSpeed: Number = 0;
    public var _isDragging: Boolean = false;
    public var _angle: int;
    private var _radius: int;
    public var _amplitudeX: Number;
    public var _amplitudeY: Number;

    public function Joystick() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageInit);
    }

    private function stageInit(e: Event): void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageInit);

        _startX = x;
        _startY = y;
        _radius = background.width / 2

        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, on_Touch);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, on_TouchEnd);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, on_enterFrame);
    }

    protected function on_Touch(e: TouchEvent): void {
        _isDragging = true;
    }

    protected function on_TouchEnd(e: TouchEvent): void {
        _isDragging = false;
    }

    protected function on_enterFrame(e: Event): void {

        if (_isDragging) {
            _angle = Math.atan2(root.mouseY - _startY, root.mouseX - _startX) / (Math.PI / 180);
            rotation = _angle;
            stick.rotation = -_angle;


            stick.x = mouseX;
            if (stick.x > _radius) {
                stick.x = _radius;
            }
        } else {
            _xSpeed = -stick.x * _tension;
            stick.x += _xSpeed;
        }

        _amplitudeY = Math.sin(_angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * (stick.x / 8);
        _amplitudeX = Math.cos(_angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * (stick.x / 8);


    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;`

Don't use `TouchEvent.DRAG`, use `TouchEvent.MOVE`.

You shouldn't need to separate your touch events like the guy before me said, since you've got two different instances of `Joystick`.

Comment: Using TOUCH_POINT instead of GESTURE was exactly what I had to do, Thanks !

Now i have to figure how I can substitute root.mouseX and root.mouseY because this cause conflict when i use both joystick since they both use the same coordonate.

Comment: e.stageX and e.stageY might be quite useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your joysticks by parent coordinates of touch event, including `TOUCH_DRAG` to update your joysticks' internal position. Then, if a `TOUCH_BEGIN` event is registered, each joystick should check if its coordinates are in that joystick's area by querying its own (x,y) coordinates and comparing to `localToGlobal` result, or `e.stageX` and `e.stageY`, and if it's not of theirs, exit the event listener. Also, you should use the other multitouch mode, `MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT` for this to work, because only this mode dispatches proper touch drag/move events. An example:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
private var _touchIndex:int; 
private function stageInit(e: Event): void {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageInit);

    _startX = x;
    _startY = y;
    _radius = background.width / 2

    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, on_Touch);
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, on_TouchEnd);
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAG, on_TouchDrag);
}
protected function on_Touch(e: TouchEvent): void {
    var pe:Point=new Point(e.stageX,e.stageY);
    var pc:Point=localToGlobal(new Point()); 
    // what if joystick was moved past placing? Otherwise use center X and Y stored
    // it's critical that these points must be in same coordinate system
    if (Point.distance(pe,pc)<_radius) {
        // this touch is ours, keep it
        _isDragging=true;
        // grab touch point ID
        _touchIndex=e.touchPointID;
    }
}
protected function on_TouchEnd(e: TouchEvent): void {
    if (!_isDragging) return;
    if (e.touchPointID==_touchIndex) {
        // it is "our" touch that's been released
        _isDragging = false;
    }
}
    protected function on_TouchDrag(e: TouchEvent): void {
    if (!_isDragging) return;
    if (e.touchPointID==_touchIndex) {
        // it is "our" touch that's been dragged
        // do your maths to update the joystick
        // make sure you will use local coordinates to update parts of joystick!
    }
}
```

And don't forget to clear those stage-attached listeners in a `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` listener for the greater good.